# Replacing Controller and function name with attribute incodeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

in htaccess or route.php where from you want you can give answer for this issue.

I Need some thing like this.if i have url :

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/headcategory_controller/head_category/Agriculture
```

than it must be replaced into

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/Agriculture
```

and if i have url like this

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/headcategory_controller/sub_category/Rice
```

than it must be replaced into

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/Agriculture/Rice
```

Can anybody solve my this issue? Please reply rapidly.

.htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(developer)/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [NC,L,R=302]

</IfModule>
```

By This -> ERROR 404 - Not Found!

Comment: in your second examle of a url you want Agriculture, but I don't see where it is in the full url. It is part of the result query that returns Rice?

Comment: Ok Here i have to add code to get "Agriculture" first that is ok.But sir how can i manage the class name and function name so that it becomes a clean url with showing only category or category/subcategory.

Comment: if you want to try a non route/htaccess option you could try a lookup function in your controller

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(developer)/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: First of all thanks for give a while of yours ,Sorry sir but its do nothing for me when i replace .htaccess file it gives 404 error.

Comment: This redirects `/developer/headcategory_controller/head_category/Agriculture` to `/developer/Agriculture` is it not happening for you?

Comment: No sir when i replace the code in my project's .htaccess you give me it will give 404 not found page.

Comment: Make sure to place this rule **before all other rules you have**

Comment: Also can you post your current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Ok sir i have mentioned .htaccess in question now as you reply

Comment: Make sure you have .htaccess and mod_rewrite enabled in your system and above code is in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess file`

Comment: Sir if not set than how can we enabled it?

Comment: Well every server is different config. You can just search on Google for your server and there will be many of helpful articles on that.

Comment: Ok sir thanks a lot it was awesome chat with you while fixing issues.thanks so much.

Comment: After making sure you have .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled, you can retest this rule.

Comment: Yes sure sir i m checking for that

Comment: can i ping you when got any trouble on this issue?

Comment: Yes definitely leave a comment here and I will attend whenever I am here.

Comment: ok Thank you so much sir so nice of you.like way you love to fix programming bugs.

Comment: NO sir its not working even after i set .htaccess and mod_rewrite enabled.Can you tell me the other way to hide controller name in htaccess or routes.php file?

Comment: Did you try this URL: `http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/headcategory_controller/head_category/Agriculture` ?

Comment: Sir i get my problem solved with routes.php but a great time to be with you Please accept a generous thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try the below in htaccess**

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

 RewriteRule ^developer/headcategory_controller/sub_category/Rice  http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

**You can try this rout.php**

```
$route['developer/Agriculture/(:any)'] = 'developer/headcategory_controller/sub_category/$1';
```